# iframe dynamic height fails in IE outside of quirks mode

Tags: javascript, vb.net, internet-explorer, iframe

currently going through this problem at work which is driving me insane as I've got nowhere and I feel like I've tried EVERYTHING.

Basically I want an iframe height to adjust depending on the content within in.  This works fine for FF, Chrome, Safari but it stays with a 200px height in IE unless in Quirks mode.  To get around this I've attempted several javascript and jQuery workarounds without any success.

My attempts have included stuff along the lines of:

- http://ramanisandeep.net/2009/12/16/how-to-dynamically-adjust-an-iframe%E2%80%99s-height/
- http://www.iframehtml.com/iframe-scripts.html#resizeable-iframe

Generally I get an error saying access is denied or 'Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'document': object is null or undefined'

Has anybody experienced a similar problem?  Live demos I've found online seem to go mental when I switch IE to anything but quirks mode.

**EDIT**

Can anybody tell me why or suggest why this site: http://host.sonspring.com/iframe/ does what I want it to in IE8/9.  Yet when I download it and follow the tutorial or use the jQuery plugin...it doesn't work at all.  And this is downloading their version, not trying to even make it work on my own project!

Comment: This is a common problem.  I've found that almost no solution is perfect, but if you fudge 20px or so on the bottom of the page, most of those jQuery plugins out there work:  http://www.lost-in-code.com/programming/jquery-auto-iframe-height/

Comment: Hi Brad, In the example you give it doesn't seem to work?  For me at least it seems they just produce a huge iFrame, they don't actually dynamically re-adjust the height.

Comment: You need to post the code for what you are trying to do, if you need specific help.

Comment: The project is too large and the only demo I've actually found online that genuinely works in IE8/9 is the one I posted in my edit.  In the demo of your example http://www.lost-in-code.com/wp-content/projects/auto-iframe-height/ The iframe is just set to a huge height and doesn't actually adjust in height depending on what you click, that's even in chrome etc, not just IE8/9.

Comment: You need to break down your example into the smallest reproduceable piece.

Comment: That's what I am currently doing, just make a dummy page with a sole iframe working as I want it.  Can I ask if the functionality is the same for you - the demo works correctly then you download the example and it doesn't work?